# Displaying clip with moviepy in python (not ipython)

Tags: python, python-2.7, moviepy

in moviepy's website an example is displayed on how to display a clip using ipython. Here it is:

```
from moviepy.editor import *
clip = VideoFileClip('some_file.mp4')
ipython_display(clip=clip)
```

Seems it should be trivial, but I 've searched and haven't found anything about how to do the same for python... How would one go about this / is there a pointer to an example?

Comment: Why does it seem trivial? iPython is used precisely because it does lots of stuff under the hood which Python doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a standard python console, use `clip.show()` for displaying an image or `clip.preview()` to preview the video. This uses Pygame as a backend to display things. Tell us if it works.